# error in /modules/mod_feed/helper.php

Tags: php, joomla

I am getting a warning after PHP update

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /modules/mod_feed/helper.php on line 42

I had faced this issue before and at that time I have used `$v=new stdclass();`. But the issue was not in a Joomla site. Now the same issue with a joomla site. My code [link is here](http://code.google.com/p/scanbilt/source/browse/trunk/modules/mod_feed/helper.php)

What I should change in this file? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need

```
$feed->image = new stdclass;
```

before line 42. This is an `E_STRICT` level warning. These are designed to alert you to code smells (like auto-creating arrays / objects).